Langchain Prompt With More than One Type of Context
I am using langchain to perform retrieval augmented generation (RAG). The issue is that whenever the user asks a question, I have two different "types" of context. To make this as simple as possible, assume I have PDF1 ... PDF203 that form part of Set A.  I have PDF204 and PDF305 that form part of Set B. Based on inputs from the user, the app will choose "a" PDF from Set A. In theory the prompt should look like this:
PROMPT_CONTEXT_TEMPLATE = """

You are an expert in [REDACTED]. When you answer the user's question [input] you should compare the answer you get if [context from set A] is relevant with the answer you get if [context from set B] is relevant. Please emphasize the differences between the answer you would get under these two scenarios.

# Question 
{input}

{context from set A}

{context from set B}
"""

The problem is that after looking at various alternative precedents like multi-factor agents etc. I have not seen any precedent where someone provides two different "types" of context to the LLM. In other words, in the prompt, there is only one {context} variable. The "brute force" way of doing this, I suppose, is to just ask the user's question using context from set A and then ask the user's question using context from set B and then, finally, ping the LLM a third time and just ask it to compare the differences between the two.  I was hoping for a more elegant solution, however.

What you call the "brute force" way probably have less chance of the LLM mixing the contexts. But you can try to ask him to do all the steps one by one in a single prompt: Like "first generate an answer using only context A, then generate an answer using only conext B, finally compare the 2 answers generated". Key here might be to evaluate carefully on a benchmark of examples where you deliberately create the contexts with different informations

But when you actually create the prompt, you have to specify a single context as follows:
  PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
      template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]
  )

No?  So, in your prompt template you may refer to two different contexts but how do you 'feed' them to your PROMPT separately?  I have not found any example of that, and I don't see that as an option in the documents.
